# Show that there is a symmetric matrix A such that $\forall g\in G,\rho(g)^tA\rho(g)=A$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, inner-products

Let $G$ be a finite group, $n$ a positive integer and $\rho: G \to 
GL(n;\mathbb{R} ) $ a homomorphism. Show that there is a positive definite symmetric
$n\times n$ matrix A such that $\forall  g\in G, \rho(g)^tA\rho(g)=A $.

Comment: Please give some information about how far you have got and where you are getting stuck.

Comment: Is this from a course in representation theory?

Answer (score 3):

An attack that works is the following:

1. Let $(,)$ be the usual inner product on $\Bbb{R}^n$. Define a "new" inner product $\langle,\rangle$ by the formula (for all $x,y\in\Bbb{R}^n$)
   $$
   \langle x, y\rangle=\sum_{g\in G}(\rho(g)x,\rho(g)y).
   $$
   Verify that this is, indeed, an inner product.
2. Verify that $\langle x, y\rangle=\langle \rho(g)x, \rho(g)y\rangle$ for all $x,y\in\Bbb{R}^n$ and all $g\in G$.
3. Recall from linear algebra that any inner product on $\Bbb{R}^n$ is of the form
   $$
   \langle x,y\rangle=x^tAy
   $$
   for some positive definite symmetric matrix $A$.

Hmm. I guess I'll stop here.

Comment: This kind of averaging is ubiquitous in representation theory. Usually one normalizes things by dividing the new inner product with $|G|$, but that is not necessary here.